# Compilar y ejecutar un .cpp en Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Usualmente compilo y ejecuto mis archivos .cpp en CodeBlocks o Dev C++. Recientemente opté por cambiarme a Visual Studio para probar el entorno y ver si me sentía más cómodo o no.

Como dije anteriormente, vengo de los IDEs básicos para compilar y ejecutar este tipo de archivos. He investigado en Internet y no encuentro alguna respuesta que satisfaga mi necesidad.

Quiero saber **cómo compilar y ejecutar un archivo .cpp en VS** así como en los otros IDEs. **¿Hay algún otro proceso diferente al de los otros IDEs? ¿Cuáles son los pasos a seguir?**

Agradecería sus respuestas.
Este es la interfaz que tengo hasta el momento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pulsa `F5` y deja que suceda la magia.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster me parece que no lo abrio como solucion y por eso no le va a dar pelota... fijate que ve carpetas.. no deberia ver carpetas en VS.. o en el 2019 me cambiaron todo?

Comment: No me puedo fijar @gbianchi mi vista ya no es lo que era, no lo veo bien ni con la imagen ampliada xD

Comment: Te dejo la secuencia de pasos [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-a-standard-cpp-program-cpp?view=vs-2019), no parece haber una etapa en particular ni pasos extras comparado con otro IDE. Saludos.